# can't Map Network Drive on Windows 7 desktop to Azure VM Windows server 2012 drive C

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, azure

On Azure VM I set C: properties to share C for my account (username and pw on both my Windows 7 desktop and my Azure Windows VM).

Then, on Windows 7 desktop I do Map Network Driver setting Folder: to \\C

Also tried adding another share:  DrvC but didn't work

Comment: Is it a standalone VM or is it connected to a virtual network? If the latter, do you have a VPN connection between your network and the Azure virtual network where the VM resides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are connecting to the Azure VM through RDP. If so, what you are trying to do is not possible.

If you want something like the above, one way would be to connect your Windows 7 machine and Azure VM, both, to a VPN connection. SMB based file shared does not work (reliably) over just the internet, mostly because ISPs block SMB ports for security. That is why you need a tunnel like VPN so that your SMB shares are visible.